# What is the current REST URL endpoint for badge definitions for work.com badges?

Tags: rest-api, work.com

I was reading through this doc on how to change the default badge that is used in the Thanks! quick action. But the endpoint url mentioned is a much older version.

[Work.com Quick Guide:
Changing Default Badge](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153000000360j5AAA/)

Answer (score 2):

Work.com has undergone lot of changes and only reference that I think is reliable is its data model

[image]

Since everything is an object here ,you can use [REST API's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) for object to do POST,PATCH or GET calls .

A simple example of REST call to get all badge definitions would be as below

[image]

An example to fetch more details about each of badge defination would be

[image]

Comment: So is there not an attribute for default badge anymore?

Comment: No there is not .Thats the short answer :)

Comment: Is there a long answer that includes me changing the default badge? I was thinking maybe a macro. But the Thanks! quick action in case feed does not show up in the macro instructions.